# SQL group column where other column is equal

Tags: sql, join, group-by

I'm trying to select some information from a database. 
I get a database with columns like:

Ident,Name,Length,Width,Quantity,Planned

Table data is as follow

```
+-----------+-----------+---------+---------+------------+---------+
|   Ident   |   Name    | Length  | Width   | Quantity   | Planned |
+-----------+-----------+---------+---------+------------+---------+
|   12345   | Name1     | 1500    |    1000 |         20 |       5 |
|  23456    | Name1     | 1500    |    1000 |         30 |      13 |
|  34567    | Name1     | 2500    |    1000 |         10 |       2 |
|  45678    | Name1     | 2500    |    1000 |         10 |       4 |
|  56789    | Name1     | 1500    |    1200 |         20 |       3 |
+-----------+-----------+---------+---------+------------+---------+
```

my desired result, would be to group rows where "Name,Length and Width" are equal, sum the "Quantity" and reduce it by the sum of "Planned"
e.g:

```
- Name1,1500,1000,32 --- (32 because (20+30)-(5+13))
- Name1,2500,1000,14 --- (14 because (10+10)-(2+4)))
- Name1,1500,1200,17
```

now I got problems how to group or join these information to get the wished select. may be some you of can help me.. if further information's required, please write it in comment.

Comment: The last result set should be `Name1,1500,1200,17` if i am not wrong

Comment: you are totally right!!! .. fixed.. thanks

Comment: `(20+30)-(5+13)` is `32`, not `37`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve it by grouping your table and subtract sums of `Quantity` and `Planned`.

```
select
     Name
    ,Length
    ,Width
    ,sum(Quantity) - sum(Planned)
from yourTable
group by Name,Length,Width
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 

A1.Name,A1.Length,A1.Width,((A1.Quantity + A2.Quantity) -(A1.Planned+A2.Planned))

from `Table` AS A1, `Table` AS A2

where A1.Name = A2.Name and A1.Length = A2.Length and A1.Width = A2.Width

group by (whatever)
```

So you are comparing these columns form the same table?

Comment: What you mean by group by (whatever)